# Cordova CLI deploy to plugged Windows phone

Tags: cordova, cordova-cli

I want to use Cordova **CLI** to deploy to my USB plugged Windows Phone.
Unfortunately the following command deploys to my laptop instead of the device.

```
cordova run windows
```

Any idea how to fix without using Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `cordova run windows --device -- --phone` command instead to run on device.
Plus `cordova run windows --list` will show all available targets.
Further you can go through [documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide_platforms_win8_index.md.html#Windows%20Platform%20Guide) into "Deploy the app" section.

Comment: If you use an old WP, you have to use `cordova run wp8 --device`

Comment: Nowadays (windows 10 phone): `cordova run windows --device -- --arch="x64" --phone`